# How to get value in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I remember that in kotlin language there is a option to get value by `get()` property, but can't find how to write it.

What I mean is: I have a `LiveData` into my `ViewModel` and I need that access to post in `LiveData` has only `ViewModel` and outside just option to get for subscribe.

How I implemented it for now is

```
class MyViewModel(ctx: Context) : AndroidViewModel(ctx as Application)
{
    private val _showLoadingPB = SingleLiveEvent<Boolean>()

    fun showLoadingPB(): SingleLiveEvent<Boolean>
    {
        return _showLoadingPB
    }
...
}
```

But I remember that there is an option to write it like this

```
class MyViewModel(ctx: Context) : AndroidViewModel(ctx as Application)
{
    private val _showLoadingPB = SingleLiveEvent<Boolean>()

    val showLoadingPB: SingleLiveEvent<Boolean>
        get() => _showLoadingPB
}
```

How to make it works?

Answer (score 1):

I remembered how it should be

```
class MyViewModel(ctx: Context) : AndroidViewModel(ctx as Application)
{
    private val _showLoadingPB = SingleLiveEvent<Boolean>()

    val showLoadingPB: LiveData<Boolean>
        get() = _showLoadingPB
}
```

This way user can't assign new value to your `SingleLiveEvent` as well as post new event in `LiveData`, he can just observe it.